# Sum up set of values based in a column and collapse rows based on conditions in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query for transforming a table in Bigquery. I have a table where I need to sum up certain rows based on specific conditions in two columns.

[image]

I need to collapse rows where I have Occ= S1 and MT = English for a unique combination across code,UR and gen. pct values should sum up to a single row as follows -

[image]

Comment: can you clarify the logic  - why first and second rows where combined? and why third and forth? By reading your question initially I thought you wanted to combine first and third into one, but leave second and forth as is - same as for the rest of rows - but looks like this is not a case  - so please clarify

Comment: Yes sure, I need to assign the sum of pct when MT= English and if Occ = S1, I am trying to collapse all rows by sum of pct, I need to assign English to S1. 
For e.g. the first two rows -  since the I have S1 and English for a unique group by of Code, UR and gender, S1 would be kept and the second value is discarded i.e. D2 and for MT we have sum of all English as a single row.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT code, UR, gen, Occ, MT, SUM(pct) AS pct
FROM (
  SELECT * REPLACE(IF(collapse, 'S1', Occ) AS Occ, IF(collapse, 'English', MT) AS MT)
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      COUNTIF(Occ = 'S1' AND MT = 'English') OVER(PARTITION BY code, UR, gen) > 0 AS collapse
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
GROUP BY code, UR, gen, Occ, MT
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row code    UR      gen Occ MT      pct  
1   128     Rural   F   D2  Ao      0.77     
2   128     Rural   F   D3  Ao      0.38     
3   128     Rural   M   D4  Ao      0.89     
4   128     Rural   M   D5  Ao      0.02     
5   128     Urban   F   S1  English 0.63     
6   128     Urban   M   S1  English 0.63
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation with some conditional logic:

```
select code, ur, gen,
       coalesce((case when cnt_s1 is null then occ end), 'S1') as occ,
       mt,
       sum(pct) as pct
from (select t.*,
             countif( occ = 'S1' ) over (partition by code, ur, gen, mt) as cnt_s1
      from t
     ) t
group by code, ur, gen, occ, mt;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - i get an -unrecognized name s1 at line 2 -error
also, there should be a criterion for MT as English too.

Comment: @JASONMENDES . . . The `s1` was a typo.  This should handle the `mt` side as well.